Having a problem with Spatie media in laravel
I have this Factory code that should take a dummy photo that I have in my public folder and add it to the media table for the 'passport_photos' collection :
    public function configure()
    {
        return $this->afterCreating(function (Passport $passport) {
            $dummyImagePath = public_path('dummy-passport-photo/dummy-passport-photo.jpg');

            try {
                $passport->addMedia($dummyImagePath)
                    ->preservingOriginal()
                    ->toMediaCollection('passport_photos');
            } catch (FileDoesNotExist $e) {
                Log::error('Dummy passport photo not found: ' . $e->getMessage());
            } catch (FileIsTooBig $e) {
                Log::error('Dummy passport photo is too big: ' . $e->getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

however when I seed, it only make one entry and store the photo in the storage file along with a preview then the terminal gives this error:

Call to undefined function Spatie\Image\Drivers\Gd\imagecreatefromstring()

Gd is installed i've checked
I also tried to change the draiver to imagick but it gave this error:

Class "Imagick" not found
and the same thing happen (creating one entry before it crash)


I think you need to verify GF Installation with this code
<?php
if (extension_loaded('gd')) {
    echo "GD is installed and enabled.";
} else {
    echo "GD is not installed or not enabled.";
}
?>

And you can see the error message with try-cath debugging.

GD is installed and enabled. I get this when running
<?php
if (extension_loaded('gd')) {
    echo "GD is installed and enabled.";
} else {
    echo "GD is not installed or not enabled.";
}
?>


try enabling gd extension on php.ini by uncomment extension=gd

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The OP already wrote "Gd is installed" - so what makes you think that enabling it once more helps?
